# ¿Como obtener los valores latitud y longitud de google maps con vue?

Tags: vue.js, google-maps

Hola implemente google maps a mi proyecto en vue y laravel, lo que quiero es obtener los datos de la latitud y longitud, seguí este blog
http://cristiantorresalfaro.blogspot.com/2020/08/mostrar-ubicacion-en-google-map-vue-js.html
si me muestra el mapa, lo unico que falta serian los valores, para poder guardarlo en mi base de datos, ayuda porfavor. Así lo tengo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así es el código de mi archivo googleMap.vue

```
<template>
  <gmap-map
    :center="center"
    :zoom="16"
    style="width: 100%; height: 250px"
  >
    <gmap-marker
      :key="index"
      v-for="(m, index) in markers"
      :position="m.position"
      :title="m.title"
      :clickable="true"
      :draggable="true"
      @click="center=m.position"
    ></gmap-marker>
  </gmap-map>
</template>
<script>
  export default {
    data () {
      return {        
        center: {lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude},
        markers: [{
          position: {lat: this.latitude, lng: this.longitude},
        }]
      }
    },

    props: {
        latitude: Number,
        longitude: Number,
        title: String
    }
  }
</script>
```

Solo me muestra datos de mi archivo CrearFacturaComponent, también quisiera que se muestre lo del archivo googleMap.vue
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2):

1. Para que vue devtools lea tu componente map, debes especificarle un nombre válido dentro del export default, como se muestra en el ejemplo: name : 'Map'
2. Tengo el mismo problema, no he podido obtener latitud y longitud, pero haciendo varias pruebas y usando el evento bounds_changed, podemos obtener estos resultados, pienso que pueden ser útiles para de alguna forma calcular/obtener ubicación.

// vue2-google-maps con Nuxt 2.15.3

```
<template>
 <gmap-map
  //...
  @bounds_changed="setCoordinates"
  @dragend="coordinates"
 >
  <gmap-marker> </gmap-marker>
       
</gmap-map>
</template>
    <script>
export default {
  name: 'Map',
  
 data() {
    return {
     coordinatesMap: null,
    }
  },

 methods: {
     setCoordinates(newCoordinates) {
      this.coordinatesMap = newCoordinates
    },
    coordinates() {
      //Do something
      console.log(this.coordinatesMap.Ab)
      console.log(this.coordinatesMap.Ua)
    },
  },
}
</script>
// Console
{
"h": 47.371524727114014,
"j": 47.395845736123185
}
{
"h": -1.2169070898230872,
"j": -1.183604782694181
}
/** Datos relacionados, según el contenido del objeto al copiar directo de consola **/
{
"south": 47.371524727114014,
"west": -1.2169070898230872,
"north": 47.395845736123185,
"east": -1.183604782694181
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]